# If mail() is "not very efficient", what is a better method to send email?

Tags: php, email, smtp

My first question is if (1) it is possible to send mail by php mail function from local-home running Apache-PHP-SMTP server without port-forwarding on the ADSL-router?

My second question is: I found this text about mail function in the PHP.net:

> This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email , which is not very efficient

(2) why it is not efficient (3)what is the efficient way? as i know, the mail server do the same thing.

Comment: It adds a small bit of overhead to [re]connect to the SMTP server. Unless you are sending *many* emails *very quickly* it is Sufficiently Efficient - use it, and don't worry about the note. Wrt the first question: all PHP does is connect to *a* SMTP server and hand off the message, thus such is possible given a suitable local SMTP server/configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question what is a better method to send an e-mail?

**USE MandrillApp**

You can get as much as 12000 free e-mails for a month.

[LEARN HOW TO USE MANDRILL HERE](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEQQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codecademy.com%2Fcourses%2Fweb-intermediate-en-hwulM&ei=MvTlU_nlJYSD8gWQ_oLABw&usg=AFQjCNF-jIsNqF73PErIOZSpNKxLk4wnTQ&sig2=GMjQ-y2n6s5bvCWjxkkrCg)

Trust me I have been using Mandrill for emails and it is far more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

The efficient way and easy way to send mail is through PEAR package called [Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected)

Because you can configure any type of SMTP, I even used with AmazonSES SMTP.